# Handling of timezone in mongodb $dateToString with java driver

Tags: mongodb, timezone

I import an excel sheet to my mongodb collection. In excel sheet a date value was `08-03-2021  00:00:00`. It is stored in mongodb as UTC. Current timezone is 4 hours ahead of UTC. So it is stored in mongodb as `2021-03-07T20:00:00.000+00:00`. While displaying in front end I want it displayed as `08-03-2021`. I tried to use  a projection like this from my java backend:

```
Bson firstProjectVLBson = BasicDBObject.parse("{$project: {" 
            + "purchaseOrderCreationDate:{$dateToString: { format: '%d/%m/%Y', date: 
              '$purchaseOrderCreationDate', "
            + "timezone: '" + zoneId + "' }},"
            + "}}");
```

zoneId I am getting like this:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
String zoneId = zone.getID();
```

It worked in my local environment. But when deployed in test environment it gave error:

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "Command failed with error 40485 (Location40485): 'unrecognized time zone identifier: "Etc/UTC"' on server 10.254.8.220:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "unrecognized time zone identifier: \"Etc/UTC\"", "code": 40485, "codeName": "Location40485"}"
path: "/pmt/api/v1/pm/analytics/getXXX/296532a1-1235-4703-845e-1544864411da"
status: 500
timestamp: "2021-03-24T18:29:56.854+0000"
```

I think if I pass the time zone in "America/New_York" format it will work.  Using mongodb 4.0.0